# Pl/SQL Looping through the values of a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function TotalIncome
   ( name_in IN varchar2 )
   RETURN varchar2
IS
   total_val number(6);

   cursor c1 is
     select monthly_income
     from employees
     where name = name_in;

BEGIN

   total_val := 0;

   FOR employee_rec in c1
   LOOP
      total_val := total_val + employee_rec.monthly_income;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN total_val;

END;
```

In this example, I am being told that that we are looping through the values of but what I dont understand is if we are looping through the values why is `employee_rec.monthly_income` necessary ? Also, when I do a `FETCH` on `employee_rec` I seem to be getting an error so I guess they are different from each other.

Comment: Why so complicated? `select sum(monthly_income) from employees where name = name_in` does the same thing without a cursor - and will be **much** more efficient.

Comment: I am just using this as a toy example to understand cursors

Comment: Change the name of your parameter from "name_in" to "name" to match the column name, and in the cursor refer to it as totalincome.name. Your return type should be numeric and the total_val should have a type of employee_rec.monthly_income%type, or maybe just number. Consider placing the SQL for the cursor in the FOR statement rather than using a named cursor -- it will be easier to support if the code reviewer does not have to look around to see what c1 means. At the very least, give it a decent name ;) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are looping through *records* in the result set.

in other words:

```
FOR employee_rec in c1
```

means open the cursor `c1` and perform a fetch on it. For each row found, assign the row record to a record variable called `employee_rec`.

so to reference `monthly_income` in that, you have to say `employee_rec.monthly_income` and not just `monthly_income` on its own.

> when I do a FETCH on employee_rec

employee_rec is not a cursor (its a variable) so you don't fetch from it. In this case the fetch from `C1` is handled implicitly by the for loop, so no explicit fetch on  your part is required.

Answer (score 3):

You are not "looping through the values", you are looping through the records returned by your cursor. In your case, your records only contain one field -- `monthly_income` -- but in general, a record can contain many fields, which you can use as you see fit in each loop iteration.